# How to address the next iter with python (xml.etree.ElementTree)?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
  <storage>
    <record>
      <values>
        <points>99999999</points>
        <points>Mr</points>
        <points>Marvin</points>
        <points>Homes</points>
        <points>hardware</points>
        <points>true</points>
        <points>de</points>
        <points>6</points>
        <points>false</points>
      </values>
    </record>
  </storage>
```

Hello,

I am trying to change some xml values with python ( xml.etree.ElementTree ).
This is a small part of a xml data.

```
appelation=re.compile("Mr")
for fname in root.iter('points'):

    if appelation.match(str(pTest)):
        fname.text="New Mr/Mrs"
        ## here i am trying to edit the next iter (<points>Marvin</points>)
        ##fname.next().text="New name" -> doesnt work
```

Any suggestion how to address the next iter?
The xml files has alot of tags called <"points"> and the values are always diffrent.

Comment: You could set a variable (match_found = True) and then continue to the next iteration

Comment: I didn't quite understand the problem. What is `pTest`'s value?

Comment: Which ElementTree are you using? xml.etree.ElementTree or lxml.etree?

Comment: Yeah sorry i miss a part from the code: pTest=fname.text
I try to match the text of the "points" and try to resolve it with regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `xml.etree.ElementTree` since it is part of the standard library. Consider the following snippet:

```
appelation = re.compile('Mr')
points = root.iter('points')
for node in points:
    if appelation.match(node.text):
        node.text = 'Monsieur'
        node = next(points)
        node.text = 'Francois'
        break
```

ElementTree.dump(root)

In this snippet, `points` is an iterable which we use to get the next points and search. Once we found the node that we are looking for (Mr), we can do something to that node and the next node (by calling `next` on the said iterable).

The output:

```
<storage>
    <record>
      <values>
        <points>99999999</points>
        <points>Monsieur</points>
        <points>Francois</points>
        <points>Homes</points>
        <points>hardware</points>
        <points>true</points>
        <points>de</points>
        <points>6</points>
        <points>false</points>
      </values>
    </record>
  </storage>
```

## Update

If you want to modify this node, next node, and previous node; then you need to keep track of previous node as there is no way for an iterable to go back. The simplest way is to use a stack (a `list` or `collections.deque` will do):

```
appelation = re.compile('Mr')
points = root.iter('points')
nodes_stack = []
for node in points:
    if appelation.match(node.text):
        # Modify this node
        node.text = 'Monsieur'

        # Modify next node
        next_node = next(points)
        next_node.text = 'Francois'

        # Modify previous node
        previous_node = nodes_stack.pop()
        previous_node.text = 'modified'

        # Keep popping the stack the get to previous nodes
        # in reversed order

        ElementTree.dump(root)
        break
    else:
        nodes_stack.append(node)
```

Comment: Thank you :) thats exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: Be advised that this will raise an uncaught `StopIteration` in case `Monsieur` is the last item in the input.  You might want to catch it (using a normal `try`/`except` clause) and raise a more speaking exception instead (e. g. `ValueError("missing value after Monsieur")`) to ease debugging.

Comment: Good point. There is also a case where *Mr* not found that we should handle as well.

Comment: Is there also an opposite function like previous object? Couldnt find any to go one step back.
I am trying to do the same but now to check one "points" value and then go one step back and edit the last item.

Comment: I save the lastitem and check for match if its match i edit the last item but i wonder if there is no "easier" way.

Comment: The iterable only go forward. One work around is to put each node found into a stack (you can use a `list`, or `collections.deque` for that purpose), then pop the stack to get previous item.

Comment: I see you added the whole think to the answer Thank you :) @Hai Vu